# Как удалить из строки трех значные и более цифры?

Tags: php

Есть строка в которой куча текста и цифры, нужно удалить все цифры оставив только однозначные и двухзначные

Comment: `preg_replace('/\d{3,}/', '', $str);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то так:

```
$text = 'текст 1 текст 22 текст 333 текст 4444';
$new = preg_replace('/\d{3,}/', '', $text); // текст 1 текст 22 текст  текст
```

Comment: Если после трёх- и более значного числа идёт пробел вероятнее всего его тоже нужно удалить ну или потом прогнать строку на наличие двух проьелов рядом